# How can I get the instance of an Object from inside one of its variables

Tags: java, class, object, instance

Say that I have three classes, `Parent`, `ClassA` and `ClassB`. ClassA holds ClassB as one of its variables which is an extension of `Thread`, along the lines of:

Parent:

```
class Parent {
    private HashMap<ClassA, Letter> map;

    public void writeToMap(ClassA a, Letter l) {
        map.put(a, l);
    }
}
```

ClassA:

```
class ClassA {
    private ClassB instance;
    .
    .
    .
}
```

And then I have ClassB:

```
class ClassB extends Thread{
    //Inner variables

    public void run() {
    //do some work
    //At some point it receives an object through a Socket
    incomingLetter = (Letter) socketIn.readObject();

    //Here I need put in the Parent class' map the Letter object I just read
    //as well as the instance of ClassA that holds this one instance of ClassB
}
```

How can I grab the instance of `ClassA` that instantiates an `ClassB` object from inside `ClassB`'s object so I can add it to the map? Is this programatically possible in Java?

Comment: You have to explicitly implement that by passing classA object to classB object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can modify class B so that it hold a reference to class A passed on the constructor:

```
Class ClassB extends Thread {
    private ClassA classA;

    public ClassB(ClassA classA) {
        this.classA = classA;
    }

    ...
}
```

If class B is already created add a method `setClassA`

```
...
public void setClassA(ClassA classA) {
    this.classA = classA;
}
```

Comment: So, having ClassB hold a reference to ClassA is the only way? Isn't there something like getSuperclass, but instead of returning the super, I get the object that instantiated it? I was looking for a cleaner way than having the lower classes know the instances of the higher-level classes. Thanks for the reply, nethertheless :)

Comment: @Heinzen No, objects don't automatically remember who instantiated them, there's no way to get this in another way.